# Not able to run git svn command in windows

Tags: git, perl, github, svn, git-svn

git svn command is not working in windows. I have downloaded the latest stable version(2.33.0.2) of git for windows. I'm getting the following error while executing the git svn command.
It is strange to see that it is looking for Perl libraries in unix style path while on windows.
Please help me resolve the issue.

Error message after executing **git svn**:

> Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.dll' for
> module SVN::_Core: No such file or directory at
> /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/DynaLoader.pm line 193.  at
> /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/SVN/Base.pm line 59. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/SVN/Core.pm
> line 5. Compilation failed in require at C:/Program
> Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at C:/Program
> Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6. Compilation
> failed in require at C:/Program
> Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 32. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at C:/Program
> Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 32. Compilation failed
> in require at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn
> line 64. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Program
> Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 64.

Comment: Same error reported here with Windows 10, with the same version of Git.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a bug report available for the broken git svn command, see https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3392 and https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3403.

Try the latest git for windows snapshot, look here https://wingit.blob.core.windows.net/files/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can grab the missing `msys-expat-1.dll` from MSYS64 or a slightly older Git installation package and place it in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` (or whatever your path is).